# What is the easiest way to align images and buttons in the center of wxpanel vertically?

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer

My project is YouTube and the home page includes the videos you can watch. A video is made of a thumbnail and a button just underneath 'Play'. I would like to have a wxpython panel that is made like this...
\image\
button
\image\
button
and so on

An image at the top of the screen that is placed in the center horizontally and a button just underneath. Then just below the button of the first video, an image and then a button, so on and so on.

I tried looking at sizers and I imagine the solution will include sizers but I had a hard time understanding how it works and how I could use it to resolve my problem.

This is what I have so far (placing the first image in the center horizontally)

```
    self.image = wx.StaticBitmap(self)
    self.image.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('icon.png'))
    self.topsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.topsizer.Add(self.image, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    self.SetSizer(self.topsizer)
    self.Layout()
```

Comment: Run with what you have, remembering to add a button, but use a `wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)`. Add to sizer, image, button, image button .... There are numerous `BoxSizer` tutorials out there.

Comment: Can someone please share a code?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember, is that people can't just `share` code, unless they are doing what you are trying to do. It has to be written.
Try using this as a starting point.
The image rescaling is specific to my images, to make them the right size.

```
import wx 
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

imgs = ['ace.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png']
links = ['https://www.asite.com/ace.mp4', 'https://www.asite.com/2.mp4', 'https://www.asite.com/3.mp4', 'https://www.asite.com/4.mp4', 'https://www.asite.com/5.mp4']

class Example(wx.Frame): 
   
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title) 
             
        self.InitUI() 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()
        
    def InitUI(self): 
        panel = ScrolledPanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        panel.SetupScrolling()
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 

        for index, img in enumerate(imgs):
            bmp = wx.Bitmap(img)
            image = bmp.ConvertToImage()
            image.Rescale(70, 100)
            bmp = wx.Bitmap(image)
            video = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, wx.ID_ANY, bmp)
            button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Play", name=str(index))
            button.SetToolTip("Play "+links[index])
            vbox.Add(video, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0) 
            vbox.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5) 
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlay, button)
 
        panel.SetSizer(vbox) 

    def OnPlay(self, event): 
        obj = event.GetEventObject()        
        print("Playing ..."+links[int(obj.GetName())])
                  
app = wx.App() 
Example(None, title = 'BoxSizer Demonstration') 
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: @ethanchocron My pleasure. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers